# Connect to database after creating the PDO object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I connect to a mysql database using the following code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);
```

As you can see the code doesn't provide the database name so I can create one, but can I make a connection to the created database later in the code?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: How to connect to a database later in the code, because I would normally add the database parameter in the new PDO object.

Comment: Read PDO manual. bind_param

Comment: Another option, other than the answer in the suggested duplicate is this `mysql_select_db('testdb', $link);`. See here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers